# How do I display all the values within a 2D Array?

Tags: c#

I have a 2D array in which I want to show all the data within like this:

GridArry[]:

```
[ 1, 6, 5, 7]
[ 6, 2, 8, 0]
[ 3, 7, 1, 5]
```

This is currently my code:

```
gridArray = new int [Columns, Rows];
for(int i = 0; i < Columns; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < Rows; j++)
    {
        gridArray[i, j] = Random.Range(0, 10);
        Debug.Log(gridArray.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Print data in 2D format? or the 2D value should be extracted to 1D array list?

Comment: What output you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, however you can use [Iterator method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators) to get each row. Which makes it easier to use [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) in the result

**Given**

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetRow(int[,] array,int index)
{
   for (var i = 0; i <= array.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
      yield return array[i,index];
}
```

**Usage**

```
var test = new[,] { { 1, 2}, { 3, 4}, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };

for (var j = 0; j <= test.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
   Console.WriteLine("[" + string.Join(", " , GetRow(test,j)) + "]");
```

**Output**

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

[**Online Demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UU1ohk)

<sub>***Note*** : Depending how are you define a row and a column, you may need to switch the polarity, honestly i didn't put that much thought in</sub>

---

**Additional Resources**

[Array.GetUpperBound(Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound?view=netframework-4.8)

> Gets the index of the last element of the specified dimension in the
>   array.